# Setting value in select dropdown which is populating by ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-digest

I have an array as below:

```
hunting_lands = {"1":{"name":"forest and rivers"},"2":{"name":"safari"},"3":{"name":"sea"},"4":{"name":"Mountains"}}
```

I have a select dropdown where I use above json:

```
   <select  id="favourite_hunting_land">
       <option value ="[[key]]" ng-repeat="(key, value) in hunting_lands">[[value.name]]</option>
   </select>
```

Now I want to show a value selected for example **sea**:

**For this what I tried:**
I set hunting land dropdown menu ng-model = fav_hunting_land

```
$scope.$watch('fav_hunting_land', function() {
        $scope.fav_hunting_land = 3;
    });
```

But Then I had other onchange functions which is not working and neither does select dropdown works i.e I am unable to change values.
It worked and show 3 value selected.

All want is to show selected value in select dropdown which populates using ng-repeat.

**Update**

*I am using [[]] for expressions using interpolate.*

Answer (score 0):

Use expression

```
<select  id="favourite_hunting_land">
       <option value ="key" ng-repeat="(key, value) in hunting_lands">{{value.name}}</option>
</select>
```

EDIT:

You can set the inital value with ng-init

```
   <select ng-init="selected='3'" ng-model="selected " ng-options="c.key as c.value for c in hunting_lands"></select>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/O7xnL6v2gghqGW7AD4ax?p=preview)**

Comment: I have updated my question. I am using [[]] brackets for expressions using interpolate.

Comment: Check the plunker

Comment: I want to set a particular value

Comment: @Simer what is the value ?

Comment: value is 3. It would be any value within array I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead in the HTML

`<select  id="favourite_hunting_land" ng-model="selectedItem">
       <option value ="{{item.name}}" ng-repeat="item in hunting_lands">{{item.name}}</option>
   </select> <br>
Value selected is {{selectedItem}}`

Comment: This will give me a value instead, I want to set a value. You are telling me how to get value.

Comment: This will also set (show) the value in the dynamically populated dropdown. I have added  `ng-model="selectedItem"` in the select tag. Try running this.